# How to draw jitter plot using gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot, plotting

I'm trying to plot the data of 100x11 array in plot using gnuplot. I created a .gnu file to generate plot but unable to get jitter plot.

I'm using the below code

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1280,800 enhanced font 'Helvetica,24'
set output "coin_flip.png"

# Title, axis label, range and ticks
set title "Jitter plot of data from coin flip experiment"
set xlabel "Fairness (p)"
set ylabel "# of heads in 10 tosses"
set xrange [-0.1:1.1]
set yrange [-1:11]

# Line styles
set style line 1 lt -1 lw 4 pt 5 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "green"
set style line 5 lt -1 lw 4 pt 13 lc rgb "purple"
set style line 6 lt -1 lw 8 pt 13 lc rgb "black"

# Function definitions and curve fits
set fit logfile 'coin_flip.log'

#Fit
plot "coin_flip.dat" using 1:2 ti "Fairness(p) vs # of Heads" ls 1
```

I'm getting below result

[image]

But I'm trying to get as the below plot

[image]

Can you please help me in plotting?

Comment: There's a "jitter.dem" here https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/master/demo/jitter.dem ... My edited jitter-plot-1.txt : https://www.dropbox.com/s/z38rg8gcyepgzbv/jitter-plot-1.txt?dl=0 ... More http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/gnuplot/demo_canvas/jitter.html

Comment: I tried using below command
set jitter 

but unable to proceed successfully. Could you please help me in plotting.

Comment: Did  you try `$ gnuplot jitter-plot-1.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color "Helvetica" 72

#name of the output file
set output "CoinFlip.eps"

#size of the graph
set size 5.0,5.0

#Titles of Graph
set title "Weighted flips"

#X and Y axis labels
set xlabel "p"
set ylabel "number of heads in 10 flips"

#makes grid lines on the graph
set grid

#point size of the data points
set pointsize 15

#puts the key on the top right
set key bottom right

# Range and Domain of the axis
set xrange[0:1.1]
set yrange[0:11]


set style line 1 lc rgb "red" pt 6
# set style line 2 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
# set style line 4 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "green"
# set style line 5 lt -1 lw 4 pt 13 lc rgb "purple"
# set style line 6 lt -1 lw 8 pt 13 lc rgb "black"

#Fit

w=.5
plot "coin_flip.dat" using 1:($2+w*invnorm(rand(0))) ti "P vs Number of Heads" ls 1
```

The above gnu plot produces the appropriate output